# How to make a call from Ruby on Rails to an external PHP script?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3

**SOLVED**

I'm pretty newbie to Ruby and I need to retrieve some information from an external PHP script but I don't know how to make a call from my Ruby on Rails aplication passing the data expected for the script.

In AJAX it'd be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://externalurl/script.php",
    cache: false,
    data: "myData",
    success: function(result){
          doSomething(result)
    }
});
```

Could I make it via Net:HTTP?

Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**

I was passing less parameters than those expected for the PHP script.

The resultant code is just as Mickey said:

```
uri = URI('http://externalurl/script.php')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {'param1' => 'v1', 'param2' => 'v2', 'param3' => 'v3', 'max' => '50'})
puts res.body
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say external...  Is this script on the same server, or elsewhere?

Comment: Elsewhere. Maybe that's a problem, isn't it? :(

Comment: No, not at all.  The reason I asked is that many folks think they have to make an HTTP request to call a local PHP script, when in fact is often faster to execute PHP directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for a moment I was worried about Same Origin Policy problems ;)

Comment: You won't have problems like that, because PHP runs server-side.  If you do it correctly, the remote web server won't be able to distinguish between your server and a client.  Same-origin only applies client side where mixing stuff from different places can open up security issues, in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

There's pretty good documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) on the api.

Comment: I've already tried that, but the response it's just the default page with a link to IIS main page. The same that I get if I just put the url in my browser.